# No access to user profiles

Tags: asp.net, profile

I am using mySQL as ny db and have all the asp membership configuration in place.
I have set additional profile proerties in my web.comfig file as shown below;

```
 <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="AccountConfirmationId" type="System.String" />
    <add name="FullName" type="System.String" />
    <add name="CompanyName" type="System.String" />
    <add name="CompanyLocationName" type="System.String" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

My first question is where are the profile values actually stored? There is no additional columns created in my membership profile table.

Secondly, I am using the method outlined below to store the entered values in the registration process into the profile, from the "Next" button click event.

```
 Protected Sub RegisterUser_NextButtonClick(sender As Object, e As WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles RegisterUser.NextButtonClick
    'set Profile object and give it its property values
    Dim userProfile As ProfileCommon = TryCast(ProfileCommon.Create(RegisterUser.UserName), ProfileCommon)
    userProfile.AccountConfirmationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    userProfile.SetPropertyValue("FullName", FullName.Text)
    userProfile.SetPropertyValue("FullName", CompanyName.Text)
    userProfile.SetPropertyValue("FullName", CompanyLocationName.Text)
    userProfile.Save()


    Session("rolerequest") = ddlRegisterAs.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Session("acctconfid") = userProfile.AccountConfirmationId
    Session("completename") = FullName.Text
    Session("compname") = CompanyName.Text
    Session("compnamelocation") = CompanyLocationName.Text

End Sub
```

I try to retrieve the profile values on my admin user management page with the following method ( triggered by username selection from a dropdownlist)

```
Protected Sub ddlSiteUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlSiteUsers.SelectedIndexChanged

    Try
        Dim userProfile As ProfileCommon = Profile.GetProfile(ddlSiteUsers.SelectedItem.ToString())

        tbProfileUserFullname.Text = userProfile.GetPropertyValue("FullName").ToString()
        tbProfileCompany.Text = userProfile.GetPropertyValue("CompanyName").ToString()
        tbProfileCompLoc.Text = userProfile.GetPropertyValue("CompanyLocationName").ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblSiteUserErrMessage.Text = "User profile not found...   " & ex.Message.ToString()
        lblSiteUserErrMessage.Visible = True
    End Try

End Sub
```

All values come up as empty strings. Any help appreciated.
I am using a website project not a web application.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the property names and values are serialized and stored in the existing table columns. See this blog post for more details:
[How ASP.NET Profile Properties are serialized in the database using Sql Profile Provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/03/04/how-asp-net-profile-properties-are-serialized-in-the-database-using-sql-profile-provider.aspx)
These are the (auto-generated) columns in the profile table for my web app:

```
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[PropertyNames] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
[PropertyValueStrings] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
[PropertyValueBinary] [image] NOT NULL,
[LastUpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

In short, the profile properties are not directly accessible for querying outside of the Profile provider. For that reason I have seen several recommendations to not use the default Profile provider and instead store User details in a separate `UserDetails` table. I ended up adding columns directly to the Users table, which has so far worked fine for me, but may not be the best choice for some applications.

Comment: by existing tables are you referring to the aspnet_profiles table that created from the configurastion tool? Because that is not happening in mine as no new columns are added

Comment: What Profile provider and version of ASP.NET are you using and what tables do your currently have in your database?

Comment: Provider=mysql and all the tables created by the configuration tool, membership roles profiles users etc etc. Im using .Net 4.5

Comment: Two Questions: Does your Profiles table have any columns in it? In your Web.Config, what is the name of your Profile provider? Mine is `DefaultProfileProvider` but I'm guessing that yours may be `SqlProfileProvider`.

Comment: the mysql configuration tool generates the same tables the asp tool does

Comment: My apologies, I'm not sure how I missed that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22471/discussion-between-probackpacker-and-dinotom)